# Providing user access to save ftp images and read images in IIS 7.5 folder

Tags: php, ftp, iis-7.5

I have a web application where when a user double-clicks on an element, a php script is run to pull images from an ftp server and place on my web server in an images folder that is in the same folder that my code is running in.

I have shared the images folder and have set security so that IIS_IUSRS for the web server has read/write priv's (even tried with full control for troubleshooting).  The users are also lumped into a Group Name category so I have tried giving that Group Name full control as well.

Problem:  It will let ME ftp the files on double-click and then use them to build a page/report but it will not let any of my users do so.  My web server is IIS 7.5 and I'm on Windows 2008 R2 server.

From my searches it seems like it might be some IIS permissions but I can't figure out how to resolve it.  Any advice would be appreciated, this is the first time that I have set up this php/ftp situation.

Comment: I also have the ability to push the images to a shared network drive but have not been able to get that to work either.

Comment: `but it will not let any of my users do so` Are they getting error messages ?

Comment: They don't get error messages, they just get locked into an AJAX loop.  In your answer below by 'basic settings' do you possibly mean 'basic authentication'?  I was trying to look around based on your advice but not sure where to look.  IIS is definitely not my strength obviously.

Comment: no, I mean basic settings, which is the popup where you also point to the directory that holds your web application

Comment: I added the apppool for the site with modify and write/read priv's to the security tab in Edit Permissions and it worked.  This apppool value came from the Basic Settings tab under "Application Pool".  Not sure if that was the direction that you were identifying or not (I did  some google searches on defining basic settings and many mentioned apppool).  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your web server actually running under the user `iusr` (of group `iis_iusrs`) ? Or did you set your application to run under a different user? (which you can do in the 'basic settings' of your application in iis)

If you did specify an alternative user, that user needs to have write access to the folder.